# Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Netty Client send Message trough HTTP Proxy

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

I'm behind a corporate HTTP proxy and want to send and receive messages to/from a ActiveMQ Artemis broker in the cloud.

On the broker Netty HTTP is activated and I'm able to send and receive messages using the Netty based ActiveMQ Artemis client on a computer without HTTP proxy.

I know that Netty HTTP client can be configured to use a HttpProxyHandler but I didn't find a way to configure this with the ActiveMQ Artemis client.

Any help is highly appreciated.